I'm getting error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'
CREATE TABLE table_3 
AS
    SELECT * FROM [2023 SQL].dbo.F_table_1
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM [2021 SQL].dbo.F_table_2


Why should I "tag my RDBMS"? - please add a tag to specify whether you're using mysql, postgresql, sql-server, oracle or db2 - or something else entirely. Not all RDBMS support this CREATE TABLE .....AS SELECT ...... syntax....

You have an unmatched number of parenthesis, and your question seems to be a duplicate of How can you create a table with SELECT?

Can you try this
CREATE TABLE table_3 
AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM [2023 SQL].dbo.F_table_1 
    UNION 
    SELECT * 
    FROM [2021 SQL].dbo.F_table_2;


What did you change in the query and why does it solve the problem?
